# getting TELEGRAM post link - id with bot

Tags: telegram

How to get a post link in telegram channel with **telegram bot**

Here is how to get with telegram messenger app:

[image]

i want to get it with bot

Answer (score 2):

I found it !

It gives message like:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":99,"chat":{"id":
```

after send it with url and you can get id in `message_id`

Answer (score 1):

If you tap on the target message on telegram channels or groups, you can see the copy link option on the opened list, as you can see below:
[image]

So the Id of post is the last part of created link like :

`https://t.me/c/14715814xx/<Id of post>`